# Using Transactions with GraphDB REST API to push a file into a repository

Tags: rest, angular8, graphdb

i have the following requirement:

After selecting an ontology file i need to send it into my GraphDB-Repository. I´m programming with Angular 8.
I looked at the REST API Documentation and tried my best to understand what i need to do (i have like 3 months of experience with coding in angular [and overall actually], so all these concepts are still pretty new to me).

So i figured out i could start a new transaction, get the transaction-id and use it to submit my file. I dont know if this appraoch works, but anyway i´m not able to get the transaction-id, because it appears nowhere in the server response.
Recording to the documentation it should be in the header. But there is only the following content:
"cache-control": "no-store",
"content-language": "de", 
"content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"

Thanks in advance!

```
var config_post: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: `POST`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'text/plain',           
    },
    // responseType: 'text',
    // data: formData,      
    url: "http://localhost:7200/repositories/testdb/transactions"
}
Axios(config_post).then(function (response) {
  console.log("Got a response from GraphDB ");
  console.log(response.headers);
})
```

Comment: There is no need to initiate transaction. just `POST` your file to `statements` endpoint. Look at https://rdf4j.org/documentation/rest-api/#repository-statements

Comment: Okay thank you. I tried that, but now i seem to have difficulties with the right content type. IMO i have a turtle-file so i tried 'application/x-turtle' and 'text/turtle'. When i fetch the resource from a URL and post it to the repository it works with 'text/turtle', but here it does not. I get the following error:
error: "MALFORMED DATA: Illegal subject value: \"-\"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> [line 1]"

Comment: Looks like you are sending an invalid turtle content - e.g. there is an RDF Literal at subject position at first line. Could show us a fragment of that turtle content you are sending? And `text/turtle` is correct `Content-type` value as it is listed at https://rdf4j.org/documentation/rest-api/#content-types

Comment: Sure, these are the first lines of the file:
# baseURI: http://sites.google.com/site/smartappliancesproject/ontologies/mirabel
'@'prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
'@'prefix mirabel: <http://sites.google.com/site/smartappliancesproject/ontologies/mirabel#> .
'@'prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
'@'prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
'@'prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
'@'prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

(I did the '' around each @ just for the sake of this comment)

Comment: And then it continues like this:
<http://sites.google.com/site/smartappliancesproject/ontologies/mirabel>
  rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
  dcterms:created "14-11-2014"^^xsd:string ;
  dcterms:creator "Laura Daniele (laura.daniele@tno.nl)"^^xsd:string ;
  dcterms:description "The Mirabel ontology defines how actors can express their energy flexibility for a specific device with respect to amount, time and price in user preferences."^^xsd:string ;
  dcterms:issued "01-04-2015"^^xsd:string ;

Comment: The turtle content fetched from `https://sites.google.com/site/smartappliancesproject/ontologies/mirabel.ttl` is ok, but there is no `w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer` anywhere in that ontology file. Most obvoiusly, you are sending something else

Comment: Yeah that would make sense, but i just click the browse button and select the file. And then obviously some things in the code happen before the HTTP-POST gets sended:
 fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
      this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    }
onSubmit() {       
      var httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'text/turtle',
        })
    };

Comment: const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.fileData);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:7200/repositories/testdb/statements',formData, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          alert('SUCCESS !!');
        })
    }

Comment: Also in the console when i log fileData it has the right name and size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As Damyan mentioned, you don't need to start a transaction to upload a file. You can do something like:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-trig" --data-binary '@test_data.trig' 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/test/statements'

or

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-trig" -T test_data.trig 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/test/statements'